# Extract Option from case class while ignoring None

Tags: scala

I have a sequence of case classes like this

```
case class Foo(..., bar: Option[A], ...)
```

and I want to turn it into a `Seq[(Foo, A)]`, where I extract the `A` from `bar` and the `Seq` only contains `Foo`'s where `bar` is not `None`. Here's the implementation I have now, but the fact that it calls `get` makes me think there's a better way to do this:

```
val seqOfTuples = seqOfFoos.collect {
    case foo if foo.bar.isDefined => (foo, foo.bar.get)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
val seqOfTuples = seqOfFoos.collect {
  case f @ Foo(_, Some(a), _) => (f, a)
}
```

You might need to adjust the number of underscores, depending on how many other parameters Foo has.